# reply does not work in nservicebus

Tags: nservicebus

guys

I'm trying to send message to server and get response on client side, also I'm trying to publish another message on server using the same endpoint.

I don't get response on client side, but subscribers get published messages with success

Server side code:

```
if (!someCondition)
        {
            _bus.Reply(new BookingStatus(message, Status.Occupied));
        }
        else
        {
            _bus.Reply(new BookingStatus(message, Status.Ok));
            _bus.Publish(new RoomBooked(message, Guid.NewGuid()));               

           //some logic
        }
```

Code for config bus:

```
BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
        busConfiguration.EndpointName("NServiceBusDemo");
        busConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
        busConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
        busConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
        busConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
        busConfiguration.AutoSubscribe();

        DefaultFactory defaultFactory = LogManager.Use<DefaultFactory>();
        defaultFactory.Directory(@"..\..\..\logs");
        defaultFactory.Level(LogLevel.Warn);

        var bus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration);
        return bus;
```

Comment: What version of NServiceBus are you using? Are you trying to do Bus.Return?

Comment: Will this sample help? http://docs.particular.net/samples/fullduplex/

Comment: How is your client setup? is it an NServiceBus host? IIS? Self hosted?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?